# Google map print grey color on print

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to print a Google Maps page, When i print this page either using ctrl+P  or click on div, **it's not working in Landscape mode.**

I am running below code on Google Chrome browser version

**Google Chrome is up to date
Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

my code so far is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    @media print {
      img {
        max-width: none !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin:0;width:800px;height:1000px" onload=initMap()>
  <div class="printdiv" style="border:1px solid red;" onclick="printMap()">Print</div>
  <div id="map" style="width:800px; height:1000px;"></div>
  <script>

    var map;

    var citymap = {
      chicago: {
        center: { lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629 },
        population: 2714856
      },
      newyork: {
        center: { lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005 },
        population: 8405837
      },
      losangeles: {
        center: { lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243 },
        population: 3857799
      },
      vancouver: {
        center: { lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1 },
        population: 603502
      }
    };

    function initMap() {
      // Create the map.
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: { lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712 },
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
      });


      for (var city in citymap) {
        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: citymap[city].center,
          radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
        });
      }

    }

    function printMap() {

      alert("resize new");
      var center = map.getCenter();
      map.setCenter(center);
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      window.print();
    }

  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBOsQrXRxsQapeKuZ7j2VvK-F-3A3VhGmU">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Output

[image]

After click on print getting grey color

[image]

Comment: The code you posted works for me, at least in my browser (Chrome 69.0.3497.100).

Comment: In Layout Landscape its creating problem

Comment: Is it working fine in Landscape mode print ??

Comment: No it's not, but you didn't mention that in your question...

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: 1000px in height is too big for printing your map on one page, in landscape mode. So I am not too surprised about this weird behavior.

Comment: Even it's behave weird in height:800px also

Comment: With the map element set at 800px in height, it works for me in both modes (landscape/portrait). I suppose it also depends on your printer settings (paper size, margins, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Workaround only. You can add CSS to fix this solution.

```
#map_canvas div > img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

`map_canvas` is the id you set to map container.

Comment: Having the exact same problem and this solved it! I've been searching all over the net and yours is the first suggestion that worked. Thank you!